# Master-Detail view: DetailViewController deinit only when I push another one?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a Master-Detail view.

When I use the phone in portrait mode, and I select a row of the `tableview` in the `MasterViewController`, the `DetailViewController` is pushed by the navigation controller.

I noticed that `detailViewController` is not deinitialized immediately when it's dismissed, but only after I push a new DetailViewController by selecting anothe row of the table:

```
Master > push Detail -> viewDidLoad is called
pop Detail and return to master
push another Detail -> deinit is finally called.
```

Why isn't called at the second step? Where could be the issue?

The master detail is built using storyboards, it's actually the default implementation you get when you select Master-Detail from xCode create projects options.

Comment: My speculation is that this is done to mirror the behaviour on an iPad.

Comment: I consider this a bug in the implementation of UISplitViewController.